# ERROR Cannot find module rxjs/operators after adding Angular Bootstrap --

Tags: angular, rxjs, webpack-4, angular-bootstrap

Can someone tell me this --

I added the
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
for Angular powered bootstrap in one of the components of my .net core + angular project.

since then I have started getting error --
Cannot find module "rxjs/operators" at webpackMissingModule like this -

```
Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 
"rxjs/operators"
at webpackMissingModule 
(E:\REPRIMX\PULSEMUSIC\PulseMusic.Web\PulseMusic.Web\ClientApp\dist\main- 
server.js:11627:195)
at NgbAccordionConfig.decorators.type 
(E:\REPRIMX\PULSEMUSIC\PulseMusic.Web\PulseMusic.Web\ClientApp\dist\main- 
server.js:11627:286)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(E:\REPRIMX\PULSEMUSIC\PulseMusic.Web\PulseMusic.Web\ClientApp\dist\main- 
server.js:11630:2)
at __webpack_require__ 
(E:\REPRIMX\PULSEMUSIC\PulseMusic.Web\PulseMusic.Web\ClientApp\dist\main- 
server.js:20:30)
```

although I used

npm i --save rxjs-compat

it did not resolve.

my cli version is 6.0.8 
rxjs is 5.4.2
angular is 4.2.5

Here is my entire package.json for your perusal and scrutiny --

```
    {
  "name": "PulseMusic.Web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@reactivex/rxjs": "^5.5.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

What are are next steps I should follow? How to go about resolving this? Can you guide me step by step?
Thanks much,

Comment: Can you add your `package.json` in the question?

Comment: added, kindly take a look please, @Jota.Toledo     thanks,

Comment: see anything, @Jota.Toledo from the package.json. is there any trouble with dependencies or version mismatch ..    ?

Comment: `@reactivex/rxjs` shouldnt be necessary, seems to be a dup. package for `rxjs`. Furthermore, you seem to have divergent versions of `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat`, which could be causing your issue. Change the `rxjs-compat` version to be the same of `rxjs`

Comment: ok. i made some changes. compared to before, I commented out the line --> "@reactivex/rxjs": "^5.5.3". then I made both rxjs and rxjs-compat to be same ie. -- >     "rxjs": "5.4.2",
               "rxjs-compat": "5.4.2".          No error is different. It gives --> Cannot find module "rxjs/operators" at webpackMissingModule.
next, what else do i check pl guide,      @Jota.Toledo

Comment: The version of ng-boostrap that you are using requires higher versions of both `angular` and `rxjs`, thats why `rxjs-compat` is still not able to solve your issue. Most likely you are ignoring a bunch of warnings during npm install, so you are shooting yourself on the foot. If you want to use the library, you will need to align the package version with a compatible angular version. See https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies

Comment: yes, there were warnings and errors during the install itself and i used --> npm audit fix --force over it. okay, let me take a look at the doc. and try reinstall the NgB package again, hopefully a correct one,        @Jota.Toledo

Comment: you wouldn't believe what ultimately silved it. I just changed the index.cshtml prerender markup to --> <app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading Pulse Music...</app>
from --> <app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading Pulse Music...</app>  @Jota.Toledo      
I am curious why and how this solved it accidentally. Did it do something to bring down all relevant packages involved to a common stable version? like HCF of math? please tell me,

Comment: am reading some of the documentation relating to the above mentioned fix I applied. It appears that the markup basically brings down all the relevant packages during rendering to base version of ng2 -- thus removing the possibility of version mismatch conflict   @Jota.Toledo   ..  I hope I am correct,